# Empty variable when open <p:dialog> - JFS 2.0, Primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

how're you?

Maybe a newbie question now. Now I have one input and a "submit" button inside a form. When I click in submit, this doesn't call any method, this just opens a `<p:dialog>`. When this dialog is opened, the variable in input wasn't setted, so another input I have in  doesn't show anything.

**See the images to understand:**
[image: Before click in "submit" button]

After click in "submit" (Adicionar):
[image: After click in "submit" (Adicionar)]
This second image must show exactly the same value of the first input, but as you can see this just shows a empty input.

---

Now let's go to my code.

**Here's my JSF:**

```
<h:form id="inserirDisciplina">

    <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" id="disciplina" value="#{cursoMBean.nome}"
      valueChangeListener="#{cursoMBean.atualizarListagemPesquisa}">
      // atualizarListagemPesquisa just update the arraylist to be shown in dataTable

        <f:ajax event="keyup" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela" />
    </h:inputText>

    <h:commandButton value="Adicionar" styleClass="btn btn-md btn-success">
        <p:ajax event="click" update=":meuForm:display" render=":meuForm:dialog" oncomplete="PF('insert').show();" onerror="alert('erro');" />
    </h:commandButton>

    <p:dialog id="dialog" header="Inserir Curso" widgetVar="insert" resizable="false" modal="true" width="600" height="500" hideEffect="clip" closeOnEscape="true" focus="enviar">
            <h:panelGrid id="display" styleClass="col-lg-10 center">
                 <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
                 <p:inputText styleClass="form-control adicionar" id="nome" value="#{cursoMBean.nome}" />
             </h:panelGrid>

                ...
```

**MBean:**

```
private String nome;

public String getNome() {
    return nome;
}

public void setNome(String nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
}
```

### Edit (new View):

```
<h:form id="inserirDisciplina">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" id="disciplina" value="#{cursoMBean.nome}" valueChangeListener="#{cursoMBean.atualizarListagemPesquisa}">
                <f:ajax event="keyup" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela" />
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h:commandButton value="Adicionar" styleClass="btn btn-md btn-success" process="disciplina" partialSubmit="true">
                <p:ajax event="click" update=":meuForm:display" render=":meuForm:dialog" partialSubmit="true" process="disciplina" oncomplete="PF('insert').show();" onerror="alert('erro');" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>

<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />

<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Inserir Curso" widgetVar="insert"
                resizable="false" modal="true" width="600" height="500"
                hideEffect="clip" closeOnEscape="true">

<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid id="display" styleClass="col-lg-10 center" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <p:inputText styleClass="form-control adicionar" id="nome" value="#{cursoMBean.nome}">

        </p:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid styleClass="col-lg-10 center">
        <p:columnGroup>
            <label for="disciplinas">Disciplinas do Curso:</label>
            <h:selectManyCheckbox style="margin-bottom: 40px;" id="disciplinas" value="#{cursoMBean.listaDisciplinasDoCurso}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                <f:selectItems value="#{cursoMBean.listaTodasDisciplinas}" var="disciplina" itemValue="#{disciplina}" itemLabel="#{disciplina.nome}" />
            </h:selectManyCheckbox>
        </p:columnGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid styleClass="col-lg-10 center">
        <p:columnGroup>
            <h:commandButton id="enviar" styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right" value="Adicionar" action="#{cursoMBean.cadastrar}">
                    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" onevent="insert.hide()" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela" listener="#{cursoMBean.cadastrar}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </p:columnGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Which is the scope of your managed bean?

Comment: The scope is @Session

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code for the button:

```
<p:commandButton value="Adicionar" styleClass="btn btn-md btn-success"
   process="disciplina" partialSubmit="true" update=":inserirDisciplina:display"
   oncomplete="insert.show();" onerror="alert('erro');">
</p:commandButton>
```

Comment: Are you getting the same result as before?

Comment: Yes, nothing appears. The strange is: when I submit the <p:dialog> (leaving the input field blank) the Disciplina is registred with the correct name. So, the problem is that p:dialog don't show the name, but when I submit the dialog the correct name is submitted.

Comment: Your form id is `inserirDisciplina`, so why are you using `meuForm` everywhere? Change that and try again.

Comment: `meuForm` is the dataTable that show the `Disciplina` results. When I type something in input (outside the dialog) my dataTable `:meuForm:minhaTabela` is updated with the new matching `Disciplinas`. It's something like search in real-time.

Comment: But the dialog is not inside of that form. Or do you have nested forms?