# 'omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter' converter id is not registered

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces, omnifaces

I'm trying to create a selectManyCheckbox feature in my application, but now I'm in "converter problem". To take care this, I'm trying to use Omnifaces that already have a converter to objects.

My solution is based [on this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19883771/how-to-use-selectmanycheckbox-with-two-arraylist-primefaces) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6848970/how-to-prepopulate-a-hselectonemenu-from-a-db/6850681#6850681) (both answered by BalusC).

---

Don't know if it helps, but he is my **view** code:

```
<h:selectManyCheckbox style="margin-bottom: 40px;" id="disciplinas" value="#{cursoMBean.listaDisciplinasDoCurso}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
    <f:selectItems value="#{cursoMBean.listaTodasDisciplinas}" var="disciplina" itemValue="#{disciplina}" itemLabel="#{disciplina.nome}"/>
</h:selectManyCheckbox>
```

**And my MBean:**

```
private static ArrayList<Disciplina> listaTodasDisciplinas;
private static ArrayList<Disciplina> listaDisciplinasDoCurso;

public ArrayList<Disciplina> getListaTodasDisciplinas() {
    return listaTodasDisciplinas;
}

public void setListaTodasDisciplinas(
        ArrayList<Disciplina> listaTodasDisciplinas) {
    CursoMBean.listaTodasDisciplinas = listaTodasDisciplinas;
}

public ArrayList<Disciplina> getListaDisciplinasDoCurso() {
    return listaDisciplinasDoCurso;
}

public void setListaDisciplinasDoCurso(
        ArrayList<Disciplina> listaDisciplinasDoCurso) {
    CursoMBean.listaDisciplinasDoCurso = listaDisciplinasDoCurso;
}
```

**Disciplina:**

```
public class Disciplina {

    private int id;
    private String nome;

    public Disciplina(int id, String nome) {
        this.id = id;
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public Disciplina() {
    }

    // Methods
    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        if (!(nome.isEmpty() || nome == " " || nome == "  ")){
            this.nome = nome;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return nome;
    }

}
```

My problem is: this actually don't works. When I select some checkbox and submit, this create a new Curso but the arraylist of selected Disciplina still empty. I think the problem is that JSF can't find Omnifaces converter. This is my HTML tag in view:

```
<html xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:of="http://omnifaces.org/functions">
```

When I hover the "converter" in `selectManyCheckbox` appears a warning:

```
'omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter' converter id is not registered.
```

I putted the Omnifaces JAR inside Web-Inf/lib. To me, everything is okay, why Omnifaces don't populate my ArrayList with the selected items?

### Edit

This is the button to submit the form with the checkboxes:

```
<h:commandButton id="enviar" styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right" value="Adicionar" action="#{cursoMBean.cadastrar}">
    <f:ajax event="click" onevent="insert.hide()" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela"
    listener="#{cursoMBean.cadastrar}" />
</h:commandButton>
```

And here is the called method:

```
public String cadastrar() {

    Curso curso = new Curso();
    System.out.println("Check if listaDisciplinasDoCurso have something inside): " + listaDisciplinasDoCurso.size() +"\n");
    for (Disciplina d : listaDisciplinasDoCurso) {
        System.out.println(d);
    }


    if (!(this.getNome().isEmpty() || this.getNome() == " " || this
            .getNome() == "  ")) {

        curso.setNome(this.getNome());

        // Clearing the listaDisciplinasDoCurso 
        listaDisciplinasDoCurso = new ArrayList<Disciplina>();

        // Adding course to database
        controleCurso.adicionar(curso);

        System.out.println("Inserted. " + curso.toString());
    } else {
        System.out.println("Error: Not inserted. " + curso.toString());
    }

    limparCampos();
    atualizarListagem();

    return null;
}
```

### Edit 2

My newest code, with two forms:

```
<h:form id="inserirDisciplina">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <h:inputText styleClass="form-control" id="disciplina" value="#{cursoMBean.nome}" valueChangeListener="#{cursoMBean.atualizarListagemPesquisa}">
                <f:ajax event="keyup" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela" />
            </h:inputText>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <h:commandButton value="Adicionar" styleClass="btn btn-md btn-success" process="disciplina" partialSubmit="true">
                <p:ajax event="click" update=":meuForm:display" render=":meuForm:dialog" partialSubmit="true" process="disciplina" oncomplete="PF('insert').show();" onerror="alert('erro');" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </div>
    </div>
</h:form>

<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />

<p:dialog id="dialog" header="Inserir Curso" widgetVar="insert"
                resizable="false" modal="true" width="600" height="500"
                hideEffect="clip" closeOnEscape="true">

<h:form>
    <h:panelGrid id="display" styleClass="col-lg-10 center" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 15px;">
        <label for="nome">Nome:</label>
        <p:inputText styleClass="form-control adicionar" id="nome" value="#{cursoMBean.nome}">

        </p:inputText>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid styleClass="col-lg-10 center">
        <p:columnGroup>
            <label for="disciplinas">Disciplinas do Curso:</label>
            <h:selectManyCheckbox style="margin-bottom: 40px;" id="disciplinas" value="#{cursoMBean.listaDisciplinasDoCurso}" converter="omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter">
                <f:selectItems value="#{cursoMBean.listaTodasDisciplinas}" var="disciplina" itemValue="#{disciplina}" itemLabel="#{disciplina.nome}" />
            </h:selectManyCheckbox>
        </p:columnGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>

    <h:panelGrid styleClass="col-lg-10 center">
        <p:columnGroup>
            <h:commandButton id="enviar" styleClass="btn btn-lg btn-success pull-right" value="Adicionar" action="#{cursoMBean.cadastrar}">
                    <f:ajax event="click" execute="@form" onevent="insert.hide()" render=":meuForm:minhaTabela" listener="#{cursoMBean.cadastrar}" />
            </h:commandButton>
        </p:columnGroup>
    </h:panelGrid>
</h:form>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: I'm not seeing anywhere in the code how you're preparing the model behind `<f:selectItems value>`. So, based on the information provided so far, I'd say that it's indeed empty. That warning is an IDE quirk. The IDE being used isn't smart enough to find the `@FacesConverter` instances in the JAR. If it was really absent, it'd have thrown an exception during runtime. By the way, those properties really shouldn't be `static` ...

Comment: I love you Balusc, always answering my questions :P. I removed the static, and if the problem isn't with omnifaces, why this don't work yet?

Comment: What scope is the bean in? How are you submitting the form?

Comment: Scope is session, I will update the question with the method called when submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As to the Eclipse warning mentioned in the title,

> 'omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter' converter id is not registered

just ignore it. It's [actually](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/blob/1.7/src/org/omnifaces/converter/SelectItemsConverter.java#L47) registered via a `@FacesConverter` annotation. It's only the IDE who's not smart enough to detect the `@FacesConverter` annotated classes in JARs deployed in `/WEB-INF/lib`. It's only looking for `<converter>` entries in `faces-config.xml`. Try to actually run the webapp project. If the converter wasn't properly registered, then you should have gotten the following exception:

> javax.faces.FacesException: Expression Error: Object named: omnifaces.SelectItemsConverter not found

---

Coming back to your concrete problem, those `static` properties aren't right. Remove those `static` modifiers. Also, the `<f:ajax>` executes by default the current component, as in

```
<f:ajax execute="@this">
```

You need to specify it to `@form` if you intend to execute the entire form

```
<f:ajax execute="@form">
```

Also, the `onevent="insert.hide()"` is wrong. The `onevent` attribute should point to a function reference, not perform a function call. The function reference is in turn called three times per ajax request. Just use `<h:commandButton onclick>` for that instead.

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem, also get rid of `event="click"` it's the default already. There's no need to repeat the defaults.

Comment: When I put execute in my f:ajax, like `execute="@form"` and restart the server I can't insert Curso anymore. When I submit, the dialog is closed (as expected), but the Curso isn't added. Nothing appears in console. Please, we're almost done, keep helping me :)

Comment: Apparently there's a conversion/validation error. Add a `<h:messages>` to get notified. Don't forget to make sure that this is also covered by `<f:ajax render>`.

Comment: I changed my Ajax to don't close the `<p:dialog>` and show the error message below the "Adicionar" button. When I click in "Adicionar", nothings appears :/ Tried with `<h:messages autoUpdate="true" />` and `<p:messages autoUpdate="true" />`

Comment: So this all is inside a `<p:dialog>`? Does it have its own `<h:form>`? See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16202671/primefaces-with-managedbeans-always-return-null/16204634#16204634

Comment: Actually I have one `<h:form>` with a first input. When I input something and click in "Adicionar", a <p:dialog> is opened with a input (with the same value of the first input) and the checkboxes with the Disciplinas. When I click in the "Adicionar" inside the <p:dialog>, finally this will call "cadastrar" method. See this images to understand better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19991911/empty-variable-when-open-pdialog-jfs-2-0-primefaces 

The first input and the dialog are in the SAME <h:form>. This is the main reason why this's not working?

Comment: I edited my code but it still don't work, I will update the question with all code of this section to you understand better.

Comment: Remove the wrong `onevent`. It's likely causing a JS error (which should be visible in JS console)

Comment: Removed the "onevent" and I putted in his place 'onclick' (of course, inside h:commandButton tag). But this still don't work. The Course isn't created, do you more ideas what can solve this new problem?

Comment: When you said, "the course isn't created", do you mean that the JSF action method is not invoked at all, or that it is actually invoked, but the `controleCurso.adicionar(curso)` failed to save it in the DB?

Comment: The action method isn't invoked, because when the ajax is without `execute="@form"` the course is inserted in the DB.

Comment: WOOOOOWWWWWW I LOVE YOUUU BALUSSCCC!!! This works, this works! Omnifaces is amazing! When I change my static methods to non-static I forget to change gets and sets, and I removed to eclipse detect errors, now I found it and this is working!!

Comment: Because the problem is with the `execute="@form"`, and you always give me all help, I will give you the best answer :)

Comment: I think you should be employed by StackOverflow, you always help me and always is ready to help anyone here. :)